# in pdf remove old revisions and keep only last one

Tags: pdfbox

I am using Acrobat Reader to update "form field" value then I save file again.

1.How Can I update field value & save avoiding incremental update ?

2.Or keep it but is it possible with pdfbox to remove previous revisions and keep only last?

Because with incremental update my file size increase

Comment: As you mention pdfbox - load the pdf using pdfbox and save it again. As mentioned in an answer to another of your questions, regular saving with pdfbox does not make use of incremental updates but instead writes everything anew as a single revision.

Comment: you are right thank you for tips. apologize misunderstanding. So i can cotinue modify field value using acrobat reader then only load and save using pdfbox will remove all revisions, nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is indeed using PDFBox. If you load a file using PDFBox and immediately save it again (using `save`, not `saveIncremental`), you get a file without incremental updates, e.g.

```java
PDDocument pdfOriginal = PDDocument.load(new File("file-with-revisions.pdf"));
pdfOriginal.save(new File("file-without-revisions.pdf"));
pdfOriginal.close();
```

Alternatively Adobe Acrobat (not Reader) contains different options for saving PDFs.